# mediaelement.js - RTMP support for audio streaming?

Tags: audio, mediaelement.js, rtmp

Is there currently any support for streaming audio via RTMP using either native HTML5 or Flash fallback with MediaElement? I saw what looked like support for Video using the flashStreamer option in the video tag 'data-mejsoptions' attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is a year old but I'm going to try and answer it in the hope I can save someone the time and trouble of figuring it out.

As far as I'm aware RTMP is not supported in any of the native HTML5 audio/video elements.

Luckily mediaelement.js seems to support this protocol in here Flash version

It seems this protocol is used more commonly for videos. That is why you'll have to provide a few extra arguments to make a RTMP stream work.

Here is how I got a RTMP audio stream working with mediaelement.js:

JavaScript:

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 500,
    features: ['playpause','current', 'progress', 'volume'],
    pluginVars: 'isvideo=true',
    //Example rtmp://my-streaming-service.com/specific-stream
    flashStreamer: "rtmp://<base-url+path>",
    mode:'shim'
});
```

HTML:

```
<audio preload="none" controls="controls">
    <!-- Example rtmp://my-streaming-service.com/specific-stream/64.stream -->
    <source src="rtmp://<base-url+path>/<filename>" type="video/mp4"> 
</audio>
```

Comment: Its so strange but your example doesn't work for me in any way. I have "server" rtmp url and "stream" and I combine them and pass to flashStreamer but it doesn't play. Have you updated this example in the meantime with some code which is not here? Thanks.

Comment: No sorry @CristianBoariu, I haven't updated this example. I actually switched to jwplayer because mediaelement.js needed too much tweek'ing for most streams to even get them working. Sorry I can't help you any further...